# What does the expression "a = yield from f()" mean?

Tags: python-3.x, yield, yield-from

So, here is a python expression:

```
a = yield from f()
```

What does it mean? Where can it be used? What kind of object should `f` be? What will be the value of `a` after the expression is evaluated?

There are several questions here on stackoverflow about python's `yield` and `yield from` but I did not find an answer to this.

I understand the meaning of `yield x`, `y = yield` and `y = yield x`. Even `yield from f()` is more or less understandable. But `a = yield from f()` is something unexpected for me.

**UPDATE:**

B. Barbieri provided correct answer. Still I need to formulate it a little bit differently.

Semantic of the expression `a = yield from f()` is very similar to a function call: value of `a` would be what `f()` returns. But if `f()` yields anything, the yielded value would be forwarded to "upper level" (you can only write `a = yield from f()` inside a function, and this will make you function a generator). If after that the "upper level" sends a value back to your generator, the value will be forwarded to `f()` and the `f()` will continue.

The `yield from` allows `f()` and "upper level" to communicate while your function is running.

I guess now I do understand what this `yield from` is all about and hope this explanation would be helpful for others.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a very simple example (`yield from` can only be used inside a function)

```
def f():
    for i in range(2):
        yield i
    return 3

def g():
    a = yield from f()
    print('a = {}'.format(a))

for item in g():
    print(item)

# output:
# 0
# 1
# a = 3
```

`a` is assigned the value which the function `f()` returns. The generator `g` yields all the intermediate results.

- `f` must be a generator (something that `yield`s).
- `a` will simply be assigned the return value of `f()`

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380) :

- `f` should be a generator (which is no surprise)
- `f` should return (and not only yield)
- `f` should accept value from `send` using `some_var = yield`
- `a` will recieve the value *returned* by `f`

Here's a `f` example :

```
def f():
    while 1:
        x = yield
        if next is None:
            return "something"
        do_something_with_recieved_value(x)
```

Considering a generator `g`:

```
l = []
def g():
    while True:
        a = yield from f()
        l.append(a)
```

- whenever `f` returns, the returned value is put into `l`
- every value send to `g` via `send` will be forwarded to `f`

Note : you need to start your generator before being able to `send` it something.

```
o = g()
next(o)  # Ensure the accumulator is ready to accept values
```

I have'nt tested everything, don't hesitate to comment if anything is unclear.